# Elasticsearch version 5.1 multimatch minimum should match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

When I upgrade [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) 1.7.5 to  version 5.1 the search query result and scores changed. Both version have same settings and mappings, product, everything is the same.

this is the query:

```
 {
       "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "productName"

        ]
      },
        "size": 100, 
       "query": {
          "function_score": {
             "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                   "type": "best_fields",
                   "query": "karaf",
                   "minimum_should_match": "100%",
                   "operator": "and",
                   "fields": [
                      "productName.standard"
                   ]
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Version 1.7.5 result : https://gist.github.com/escobar4400/e45062e0e06ab251e190e2acf93f62ee

Version 5.1 result: https://gist.github.com/escobar4400/4abbe0b4760990015a632fbfa168df90

in version 1.7 when  change minimum_should_match =50% ,the result document increase ,
but in 5.1 nothing change minimum_should_match =1% and minimum_should_match =100% same result count and same document.